# C# How to replace an Event by a Delegate?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Mac OS, VS Community, C#, Cocoa application.

The following code generates a run time error.

```
using AppKit;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using System;

namespace NSTextFieldValidation
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public ViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            var fm = new NSNumberFormatter { Maximum = 999, Minimum = 0 };
            NSTextField Tbx1 = new NSTextField(new CGRect(10, 50, 100, 30));
            View.AddSubview(Tbx1);
            Tbx1.Formatter = fm;
            Tbx1.Delegate = new MyTextFieldDelegate();
            Tbx1.DidFailToValidatePartialString += TbxDidFailToValidatePartialString;
        }

        private void TbxDidFailToValidatePartialString(object sender, NSControlTextErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DidFailToValidatePartialString activated");
        }
    }
    public class MyTextFieldDelegate : NSTextFieldDelegate
    {
        override public void EditingEnded(NSNotification notification)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EditingEnded");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use
>   events or your own delegate: NSTextFieldValidation.MyTextFieldDelegate
>   AppKit.NSTextField+_NSTextFieldDelegate

I understand that it is not correct to use event and delegate at the same time. I only ask which method I need to override in my delegate to deal with "DidFailToValidatePartialString", because I did not find it (perhaps I did not look well).

Comment: Not familiar with this but can you remove the event and override the correct method in your delegate class? The exception seems to tell that you can only do one or the other. (disclaimer: never worked with this framework)

Comment: Quick googling shows it is something xamarin specific (consider to add proper tags), see if [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40416/event-registration-is-overwriting-existing-delegate) is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the Delegate class, the DidFailToValidatePartialString method is not declared like others (i.e EditingEnded). We need to add an Export attribute:

```
[Export("control:didFailToValidatePartialString:errorDescription:")]
```

I would like the Xamarin documentation to explain this.